# when's that hot guy getting here?

Tags: present-continuous

I'm watching a TV episode. Teddy's boyfriend has come to her house. The whole family is talking with him. Teddy's younger brother Gabe is reading a book on the sofa. Later, everyone is back to their own business. Teddy asks his brother Gabe to leave. Gabe says:

> Hey, when's that hot guy getting here?

I'm confused. Why does Gabe use the present continuous tense? Shouldn't he say

> When did that hot guy get here?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with the grammar - you've missed the joke.

Gabe doesn't think the guy that has already arrived is hot. So, he is either ignorantly assuming that the "hot guy" coming is someone else, or is knowingly insulting Teddy's boyfriend by saying this.

Answer (score 2):

It is surely a joke. The family has been told by Teddy about her 'hot' (attractive, handsome) boyfriend, probably at some length. Teddy tells Gabe to leave, and he sarcastically asks when the 'hot' boy is arriving (because he does not see any hot boys yet).